# How to get out of the if statement and back to the top of the while

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have this looping structure where I am trying to parse a file. I want to jump from one `if` statement to the top of the `while` loop. However when I use `continue` what I want to happen does not. When I use `break` the entire `while` loop ends. :/ Does anyone know how I can go back to the top of the loop when a condition is met? My code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

void parseActivityFile()
{
    //read in the file
    ifstream infile;
    int last_act = 0;
    int acts = 0;
    string line;
    vector<string> activs;
    int current_int = 0;
    int curr_activity = 0;
    infile.open("activities.txt");

    while (getline(infile, line))
        {
            if (line.find("===") != string::npos)
            {
                cout << "line = " << line << endl;
                ++current_int;
                if (current_int == 2) 
                {
                    string last_activs = activs.back();
                    cout << "The last activity is: " << last_activs << endl;
                    cout << "This is last activity # " << ++last_act << "\n\n";
                    activs.clear();
                    current_int = 0;
                }
                continue; //this continue statement does not jump to the top of the while
            }

            {
                if (line.find("activity") != string::npos)
                {
                    cout << "Activity found: " << line << endl;
                    cout << "This is activity # " << ++acts << endl;
                    activs.push_back(line);

                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }

int main()
{
    parseActivityFile();
    return 0;
}
```

The program above should parse a txt file that is structured like so:

```
======================
blah blah blah
  11010101 x - - - 
 kdkjueureiruer
    activity "today on mars..."
stuff:
 more data in the file i do not care about
======================
blah blah blah
  11010101 x - - - 
 kdkjueureiruer
    activity "today on mars..."
stuff:
 more data in the file i do not care about
======================
blah blah blah
  11010101 x - - - 
 kdkjueureiruer
    activity "today on mars..."
stuff:
 more data in the file i do not care about
======================
```

The output is shown below:
[image: screenshot of program output]

Comment: Your problem statement boils down to _"when I use continue what I want to happen does not"_, which is unacceptable. Present a concise [MCVE] please -- questions here must be able to benefit others in the future.

Comment: What ***evidence*** do you have that `continue` is not going back to the top of the loop.  It looks like it should.

Comment: @abelenky That is a good question. The line that says `if (line.find("===")` does not run immediately. Instead the program seems to drop back down to the line below it that says `if (line.find("activity")`.

Comment: Presumably that's because the _next_ line that is read does not contain "===".

Comment: @paddy hmmm maybe you are right. Well shucks. 0_o. So maybe it is jumping back to the top but still my program is not doing what I want it to.

Comment: What do you want it to do that it's not doing correctly?

Comment: @paddy but the next line in the file to parse is another "===" line before another "activity" line so it seems like my programming logic should work.

Comment: But you don't know that for sure, because you have not tried to debug (for example, printing out every line that is read).  Maybe your file's line endings are not correctly delimited (e.g. Windows CRLF read on non-Windows computer).  Maybe, as proposed in the premature answer that just appeared, your logic is incorrectly specified.  Maybe `current_int` is not initialized.

Comment: Now that you have posted sample input, please post an example of the exact output you expect, and contrast with the output you actually get.

Comment: @paddy That is an awesome idea. I have done this. Please see my question again and check out the output in the screenshot.

Comment: Explain why you reset `current_int`.  It seems that is only there to wait until you have encountered `===` a second time.  After that, you presumably want to output every activity.  Maybe a better solution is to take the counter out completely, and make a small loop above your main loop which simply reads lines until it encounters `===`.

Comment: I reset `current_int` so that I can start counting again. I want to find the activities between two '===' strings. When I find an activity between two '===' strings I want to obtain the last one I found. So I get that with the `back()` function of vector. Does that make sense? 0_0

Comment: It makes sense, except it's overkill unless you want to store all activities anyway, and you're also forgetting that '===' is not only the second one of the last section but the first one of the next section.

Comment: At least it makes sense. What my plan is is that I will store all the activities between two "===" and then find the last one. I am missing something with the programming logic though. Thank-you for the help @paddy. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your brackets are wrong. I have fixed them below.

**Example 1:**

```
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    if (line.find("===") != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "line = " << line << endl;
        ++current_int;
        if (current_int == 2) 
        {
            string last_activs = activs.back();
            cout << "The last activity is: " << last_activs << endl;
            cout << "This is last activity # " << ++last_act << "\n\n";
            activs.clear();
            current_int = 0;

            continue; //this continue statement does not jump to the top of the while
        }

        if (line.find("activity") != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "Activity found: " << line << endl;
            cout << "This is activity # " << ++acts << endl;
            activs.push_back(line);
        }
    }
}
```

You can achieve the flow you want with a `continue` as in Example 1.  However, you are trying to do something better suited to an `if/else if` statement.

Example 2 is a better solution.

**Example 2:**

```
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    if (line.find("===") != string::npos)
    {
        cout << "line = " << line << endl;
        ++current_int;
        if (current_int == 2) 
        {
            string last_activs = activs.back();
            cout << "The last activity is: " << last_activs << endl;
            cout << "This is last activity # " << ++last_act << "\n\n";
            activs.clear();
            current_int = 0;
        }
        else if (line.find("activity") != string::npos)
        {
            cout << "Activity found: " << line << endl;
            cout << "This is activity # " << ++acts << endl;
            activs.push_back(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that this is the logic they were looking for?  They have not provided example input.

Comment: I suppose I can't know what logic user user3870315 wanted for certain. But looking at what was provided I made an educated guess.

Comment: @paddy I edited my question to add a sample file to parse. I think this is a suitable example of the file I am trying to parse.

Comment: I tried running this with the `continue` in a different block but it still did not do what I wanted.

Comment: That is because this user took a complete stab at your question.  This happens when: (a) you don't provide sample input; (b) you don't provide expected output; (c) the user feels it's more helpful to provide a wrong answer than to ask for clarification.

Comment: @paddy I appreciate the help though. I was getting depressed. The random attempts at solving this are inspiring and help me think about the problem differently. :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is you are making random attempts, rather than performing a logical series of debugging steps to narrow down and isolate problems.  Try reading some guides on debugging techniques.